# & (ampersand) in Terraform string or/and AWS IAM policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I coudn't find meaning of `&` sign in Terraform or/and AWS IAM policy. There is an example in `Data Source: aws_iam_policy_document` ([docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document)) where you can see `Basic Example` ([docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document#basic-example), [github source](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/5575f0cb17a8aa4c71b8359ccd80c7222b1de70c/website/docs/d/iam_policy_document.html.markdown?plain=1#L65-L66)):

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "example" {
  (..)

  statement {
    actions = [
      "s3:*",
    ]

    resources = [
      "arn:aws:s3:::${var.s3_bucket_name}/home/&{aws:username}",
      "arn:aws:s3:::${var.s3_bucket_name}/home/&{aws:username}/*",
    ]
  }
}
```

I cound't find the meaning of `&{aws:username}`. I'd try to look up in AWS IAM documentation but there is only explanation how to use variables with dollar (`$`):

> *The variable is marked using a $ prefix followed by a pair of curly braces ({ }).*

[Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html#policy-vars-using-variables)

Question: What does `&` character mean in above example?

Answer (score 1):

The note callout at the top of [the `aws_iam_policy_document` documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document) explains this syntax:

> **Note:** AWS's IAM policy document syntax allows for replacement of [policy variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html) within a statement using `${...}`-style notation, which conflicts with Terraform's interpolation syntax. In order to use AWS policy variables with this data source, use `&{...}` notation for interpolations that should be processed by AWS rather than by Terraform.

In other words, this is a special syntax implemented as a special case inside the `hashicorp/aws` Terraform provider to make it easier to use the IAM policy interpolation syntax without conflicting with Terraform's own template interpolation syntax. The provider will automatically replace `&{` with `${` while it is rendering the final policy document.